# Como cambiar la ip del servidor por el dominio comprado en godaddy?

Tags: java, jsp, godaddy

Compre un dominio en godaddy y el hosting lo tengo en un servidor externo,
como le hago para que apunte al servidor y que en lugar de que se vea
la ip publica se vea por el dominio?

Gracias.

Comment: en godaddy definis los DNS (nameservers) de tu hosting, en tu hosting creas los A record que apunten a la ip.  si usas cloudflare los nameservers y el a record lo haces en cloudflare apuntando a la ip que te dio el hosting

Comment: registrer -> domain resolver (usualmente el hosting) -> ip del hosting para ese dominio (si tenes subdominios en diferentes hostings vas creando A records en el resolver con las ip correspondientes)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta,pero es un servidor que yo puse en linea , use tomcat para poner la pagina en linea y luego compre el dominio, en este caso como le puedo hacer para que no ponga la ip publica sino el dominio?

Comment: pues lo pones en la configuración `/opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml` como `<alias>` dentro de un tag `<host>`  dentro del tag `<engine>` cambiarle el puerto default ya es otro tema